# plot upper and lower bounds for Weibull

Tags: matlab, probability, weibull

I would like to know how to plot the upper and lower bounds of Weibull distribution function. In matlab, I found a function of plotting the Weibull curve fitting but without the upper and lower. This function is:

```
wblplot(x)
```

The one that I am looking to do is similar to this picture:

[image]

The data from experiments is:
data=[696700;700000;703900;705400;713400;713200;717200;712000];

I tried to apply what is written in the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/confidence-and-prediction-bounds.html#bqxtsj5-2), then I set x=696700:712000;

Based on Weibull distribution function, y-axis can be calculated by this equation:

```
for i=1:length(x)
y(i)= (i - 0.3)/(length(x) + 0.4);
end
```

When I came to Fit the data using a Weibull function, unfortunately this function does not work

```
fitresult = fit(x,y,'weibull');
```

Can you please help me to jump this obstacle ?

Comment: did you read the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/confidence-and-prediction-bounds.html#bqxtsj5-2)?

Comment: I went through the documentation but the problem in Weibull is that you only need to enter the value of x-axis. So how can I use plot(fitresult,x,y) Weibull?

Comment: You may need to write your own function to do this. @m.s.'s suggestion looks helpful. The `mle` function also might be useful.

Comment: I updated the problem and the issue now is how to Fit the data using Weibull instead of using a single-term exponential in the documentation please

Comment: Not sure what you mean by bounds. The Weibull distribution is defined on x>= 0. Therefore the lower bound is 0, and there is no upper bound. Are you talking about quantiles? Or confidence intervals on parameter estimates?